# Configure default rule for AWS load balancer listener

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to configure the default rule for an AWS load balancer listener?

I specifically want to create a rule without a condition which is what the default rule allows you to do. I have read the [docs for `aws_lb_listener_rule`/`aws_lb_listener_rule`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener_rule) but there is no mention of creating a default rule?

Answer (score 3):

I realised after writing this question that it's probably a configuration of the load balancer itself. Here it is [in the docs for `aws_lb_listener`/`aws_lb_listener`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_listener) (rather than in the listener rule):

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  ...

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.front_end.arn
  }
}
```